# Uso de los modelos Eloquent para obtener datos a partir de RAW queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy con un proyecto en *Laravel 5.2* / MySql

Imaginemos que tengo una tabla "usuarios" y otra "insignias". Un usuario puede tener una o más insignias.

En el modelo *Usuario* tengo el método:

```
public function insignias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Insignia');
}
```

En el modelo *Insignia* tengo el método:

```
public function usuario()
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Usuario');
}
```

Puedo traerme los usuarios de dos formas:

```
$users = Usuario::all();
```

o bien con:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
$users = \DB::select($sql);
```

Ahora quiero obtener las insignias de, por ejemplo del primer usuario. Con el primer método puedo hacer:

```
$users = Usuario::all();
$user_one = $users->first();
$badges_user_one = $user_one->insignias;
```

Lo que **quiero saber es si se puede acceder a las insignias, mediante el segundo método**, es decir usando *RAW queries* para traerse los datos.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
$users = \DB::select($sql);
$users = collect($users); // convierto array en colección para poder usar first()
$user_one = $users->first();
```

**Esto ya no funciona:**

```
$badges_user_one = $user_one->insigneas;
// Undefined property: stdClass::$insigneas
```

Comment: Llevas el tiempo suficiente como para saber qué la solución no va en la pregunta si no abajo en la zona de respuestas por favor lee [answer]

Answer (score 1):

Sí se puede acceder, pero no de la forma que creo que lo intentas hacer. Al ser una consulta «normal» en SQL, puedes obtener la información, pero no obtendrás más que un listado, como probablemente ya lo sabes.

Tendrías que hacer una consulta para cada insignia y posteriormente agregarla a la colección como una propiedad de la primera colección, en un array de colecciones, lo cual sería engorroso y poco práctico.

**¿Por qué no funciona `$user_one->insignias` en el segundo método?**

En el primer método estamos obteniendo la información a partir de Eloquent, desde el modelo Usuario, por lo cual Eloquent nos genera una colección de modelos de Usuario:

```
Collection {#252 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Usuario {#255 ▶}
    1 => Usuario {#256 ▶}
    2 => Usuario {#257 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Al tener este resultado, cada modelo utiliza todas las funcionalidades de Eloquent, incluyendo cargar las relaciones como propiedades dinámicas:

```
$usuario->insignias;
```

---

Con el segundo método estamos utilizando el Query builder, el cual no tiene nada que ver con los modelos de Eloquent, es simplemente una consulta a la base de datos, por lo cual al utilizar el helper collect() posterior a la consulta, estamos creando una simple colección de elementos, no de modelos de Eloquent:

```
Collection {#2109 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#1918 ▶}
    1 => {#691 ▶}
    2 => {#1944 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Esta colección no es más que un array mejorado, con todos los métodos que ya conocemos en las colecciones, pero sin ningún modelo de Eloquent, por lo que este último desconoce que sean modelos y por ende no podrá cargar relaciones ni utilizar ninguna funcionalidad de Eloquent.

Comment: Gracias @Shaz, una explicación muy interesante. Creo que lo que estaba buscando era "hidratar" los resultados. Me sonaba de un video que vi hace 4 o 5 años... He encontrado la solución aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855116 la añadire al final de mi pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Ok, aunque hidratar es un concepto algo distinto a lo planteado inicialmente en la pregunta, puesto que al final estás pasando a usar Eloquent, que es básicamente el primer método.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una solución [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855116), y pasa por "hidratar" el resultado de la consulta RAW, ya que este, de otro modo, no permite acceder a las *relaciones de Eloquent como propiedades dinámicas* ([ver explicación en respuesta de Shaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/259922/20709)).

**Código solución:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
$results  = \DB::select($sql);
$users    = Producto::hydrate($results);
$user_one = $users->first();
$badges_user_one = $user_one->insignias;

// Trace: 
dd($badges_user_one);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar el método estático fromQuery()

```
$query = DB::raw('SELECT * FROM usuarios');
$users = Usuario::fromQuery($query, []);
```

De todas formas no es aconsejable hardcodear codigo SQL dentro de tu proyecto para realizar acciones sobre datos de tu repositorio. Utilizando query builder desacoplas tu proyecto del tipo de repositorio